# How to pass a touch event to other views?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch

```
+-----------------------+  +--------------------+
| A                     |  | A                  |
| +-------------------+ |  | +----------------+ |
| |B                  | |  | | C              | |
| |                   | |  | |                | |
| +-------------------+ |  | +----------------+ |
+-----------------------+  +--------------------+
```

I have a view hierarchy as above. 
(Each of B and C takes up whole space of A, Each of them are screen size. B is added first and C is added next)

For a reason, C is getting a touch event for scroll effect
(B is cocos2d-x layer and C(scroll view) sets the B's position when scrollViewDidScroll
http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/
)

And I want to pass touch event to B or it's subviews when it's not scrolling.

How can I pass the touch event to B here?

Comment: Is your diagram representing the views and their frames also? Do B and C have different parents, then?

Comment: ah actually B&C takes up entire region of A.

Comment: are you simulating a kind of virtual trackpad? I have problems trying to understand the interaction between B and C...

Comment: normally, C(scrollView) would have B as a subview and handle the scroll, but for a reason, C & B are sibling views and B dictates C's position. I've added the link, you can look at it for longer explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same problem is covered in the [WWDC 2012 scroll view session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).

Steps are..

```
1. You hide your scrollview.
2. place dummy view where scrollview would be and attach scrollview's panGestureRecognizer to this view.
```

lo and behold touch goes to the view behind the dummy view when it's not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your context correctly, B and C do no overlap (at least not entirely) and share the same superview.

The only possibility I see is defining your own custom window, the override

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
```

to handle the touches you get in A as you need.

See [this thread on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356723/forwarding-touch-events-only-to-the-views-being-touched) for an example of changing the destination view of a touch event. You will need to build your own flow to handle the different cases you have to manage and possibly also mess with the touch coordinates by doing some kind of projection.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually B and C do overlap. Each of them are screen size. Does that affect your answer anyway?

Comment: yes, you will not to fiddle with the touch coordinates, just return the proper view from `sendEvent` (depending on the state you are: scrolling/not-scrolling), and you are done...